# Using solution on SharePoint 365

Tags: c#, sharepoint

im working with SharePoint 365, i have a problem trying to delete all the rows of the "Workflow History" list [>30,000]
and i found this code on a blog [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ibondy/archive/2014/07/05/how-to-clean-up-workflow-history-list-on-o365.aspx]
when i try to run the script i get the following error message:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=16.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Resuming run

i already did a search about it but i can only find information about SP2010

if someone can help i will appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself.
i had to install first **SharePoint 2013 Client Components SDK**
and then link the DLL's on the solution explorer **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI**